# Finding line integral of force ${\bf F}=(x+y,y^2-x)$ along closed curve consisting of 2 piece wise regular curves.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Compute the line integral $$\oint_C{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}$$ for ${\bf F}=(x+y,y^2-x)$ and $C$ is the curve which  begins at $(-1,0)$, proceeds along the $x$-axis to $(1,0)$ and returns to $(-1,0)$ by the upper part of the unit circle.

So when I calculated the line integral for the straight line segment I got 0 and for the semicircle component I got -pi, is the line integral for the line segment correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the line segment, $y=0$ so $F=(x,-x)$ and $dr=(dx,0)$. So we have
$$\int_{-1}^1 xdx=0$$ since we're integrating an odd function on a symmetric interval.

For the semi-circle part, an easy way to do this would be to switch to polar coordinates. Then we have that $$F=(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta),\sin^2(\theta)-\cos(\theta))$$ and $$dr=(-\sin(\theta)d\theta,\cos(\theta)d\theta).$$
So the line integral here becomes
$$\int_0^{\pi} [-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)+\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)-\cos^2(\theta)]d\theta$$
$$=-\int_0^{\pi} \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta+\int_0^{\pi}\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)d\theta-\int_0^{\pi} d\theta$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(\theta)|_0^{\pi}+\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(\theta)|_0^{\pi}-\theta|_0^\pi=-\pi$$